# What is Grindelwald's blood status?

Tags: harry-potter, gellert-grindelwald

On Wikipedia, if you look at the profile of Gellert Grindelwald, then you can see that the blood status says 'half-blood or pure-blood'. Can anyone  possibly give a more definite answer as to what blood status he has?

Comment: As of the end of _Deathly Hallows_, his blood status is "coagulated."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's difficult to find out anything about Grindelwald, as there is very little information about Gellert Grindelwald's past. However, by some evidence, it can well be concluded that he was in-fact a pure blood. Let me put forth some of the theories based on existing information.

The only mention about Grindelwald's family member (is in the ***HP:Deathly Hallows***) that ***Bathilda Bagshot***, (the historian and author) was his great aunt. And according to [here](http://potter-encyclopaedia.wikia.com/wiki/Bathilda_Bagshot), she was a pure-blood witch. By this we can at least say that one side of his family tree was wizard-blood.

Going ahead, Grindelwald's studied at the [Durmstrang Institute of Wizardry](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Durmstrang_Institute), which was well-known for its tolerance towards the Dark Arts. He was later suspended because even the likes of Durmstrang couldn't tolerate his level of crazy. To quote HPWikia [here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gellert_Grindelwald),

> *Grindelwald was expelled for twisted, dark experiments and near-fatal attacks on his fellow students.*

Durmstrang, as well as its known for its tolerance towards the dark arts, it could also be rigid in admitting Muggle-borns or half-bloods. To quote Draco Malfoy in ***The Goblet of Fire***,

> "Father actually considered sending me to Durmstrang rather than Hogwarts, you know. He knows the Headmaster, you see. Well, you know his opinion of Dumbledore — the man's such a Mudblood-lover — and ***Durmstrang doesn't admit that sort of riff-raff***. But Mother didn't like the idea of me going to school so far away, Father says Durmstrang takes a far more sensible line than Hogwarts about the Dark Arts. Durmstrang students actually learn them, not just the defence rubbish we do..."

Draco may well be referring to the Muggle-borns when he says 'riff-raff'. But it could also mean that he could be talking about everyone except the pure-bloods in general.

[Here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Durmstrang_Institute), on HP discussion, many reasons have been presented that indicate Durmstrang being a school that only admits pure-bloods. Thus, in my speculation, Gellert Grindelwald may well be one of them, (i.e., pure-bloods).

***PS***: Some additional proof from the upcoming movie may help get better info to improve the answer.

Comment: A great-aunt being pureblood only implies one quarter of your family tree is pureblood, not one side.

Comment: @Rawling well, as i said before, this answer is based on incomplete information and pure speculations. Hopefully the new Fantastic beasts movie will shed some light on this.

Comment: Your link for Bathilda being pure-blood is an unsourced wiki. Citing an unsourced wiki to answer a question about an unsourced wiki doesn't add much. Good quote from Malfoy, though, for which +1.

Answer (score -1):

Grindelwald hates Muggles so he could be pureblood. But Tom Riddle was half blood and he hated Muggles and killed his father. So Grindewald could be half blood. I doubt he was a Muggle born because of how bad he went. He has an equal chance of being a pure blood as much as a half blood because Dumbledore was a half blood. But we will never know probably until late *Fantastic Beasts* movies.

Comment: You have an answer here but it’s tied up in so much guesswork, speculation and multiple possibilities it’s hard to tell what it is. Ideally you should [edit] this to state what you think his blood status is and add evidence, with quotes etc., as to why you think that.